# Find the following summation quantity for a Poisson Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study

If I have a random variable $X$ with Poisson distribution with parameter $n\theta$, i.e. $P(n\theta)$, then it is required to compute the following quantity.

$$\frac{e^{-n\theta}}{(n-2)^3}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{((n-2)\theta)^x}{x!}x(x-n)(x-2n)$$

To be honest, I am not able to proceed with this. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what "$P(n\theta)$" means.  By definition, the *density* of a uniform distribution is constant on its support and what matters, then, is the definition of its support.  The nature of your expression suggests you might be working with a *Poisson* distribution, not a uniform one.

Comment: Extremely sorry. It was a typo. I will fix that. Do I need to do anything to open the question again?

Comment: Where does the variable $X$ come into this?  It doesn't appear anywhere in the sum.  It's also a little strange to see $x(x-n)(x-2n)$ in the sum: did you intend that to be $x(x-1)(x-2)$?  It would help to know how this arises in a statistical application, because often such sums can be easily determined from such information.  BTW, your title still references a uniform distribution.

Comment: I was also thinking that if it was $x(x-1)(x-2)$ then I would have adjusted that with the $x!$ term but this n is causing the difficulty?

Comment: There's no difficulty with the $n,$ because you can just expand $x(x-n)(x-2n)=x^3-3nx^2+2n^2x$ to create three sums that are proportional to the third, second, and first raw moment of a Poisson$((n-2)\theta)$ distribution when $(n-2)\theta\gt 0.$  But I suspect this expression might have arisen through some error in a preceding calculation, so evaluating this sum would only propagate that error.  What is the original problem you are trying to solve?